# Find the IP_range details from IP Address in R

Tags: r, ip

I have two tables. Table A contains 'ip_address' field and other table B which contains 'ip_start' and 'ip_end' (range of ip) along with other fields. I want to extract the details of ip_address from table B .

For example. Table A has

```
ip_address : '178.91.21.2"
```

Table B has

```
1. ip_start :  "178.91.19.0" and ip_end : "178.91.19.255"
2. ip_start :  "178.91.21.0" and ip_end : "178.91.21.255"
```

Now my query should return me the details associated with record 2 in table B.

I want achieve this in R. Can anybody suggest how it can be done?

Comment: I've got a C++-backed [iptools](https://gitlab.dds.ec/public/projects/bob.rudis/iptools) package with  much faster IPv4 conversions to integer than pure R versions. But if you just need IP conversions and not the other bits there are standalone versions [here](http://datadrivensecurity.info/blog/posts/2014/May/vectorizing-ipv4-address-conversions-part-2/).

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way. The ipv4 addresses you specify are basically the decimal representation of 8-byte hex, so they can be represented as decimal integers simply by converting as below.

> a.b.c.d = a × 256<sup>3</sup> + b × 256<sup>2</sup> + c × 256 + d

So we do this for both the test vector (`ip` in this example), and the range data frame (`ip.range` in this example) and then identify which range goes with which ip using simple arithmetic.

```
# example dataset
ip       <- c("178.91.21.2","178.91.19.30","178.91.20.100")
ip.range <- data.frame(start=c("178.91.19.0",  "178.91.20.0",  "178.91.21.0"),
                       end=  c("178.91.19.255","178.91.20.255","178.91.21.255"),
                       stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
# function to convert ip address to decimal integer
ip2integer <- function(ip) sapply(strsplit(ip,".",fixed=TRUE),function(x)sum(as.integer(x)*256^(3:0)))
# convert ip and ranges to integer
ip.int    <- ip2integer(ip)
range.int <- data.frame(sapply(ip.range,ip2integer))
# find indices, combine into result
indx   <- sapply(ip.int,function(x)with(range.int,which(x>=start & x <=end)))
result <- cbind(ip,ip.range[indx,])
result
#              ip       start           end
# 3   178.91.21.2 178.91.21.0 178.91.21.255
# 1  178.91.19.30 178.91.19.0 178.91.19.255
# 2 178.91.20.100 178.91.20.0 178.91.20.255
```

Comment: The original answer had an error: the correct radix is 256, not 255. The code above has been changed.